# 'MyFirstApp.Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'myButton' (CS0117) (MyFirstApp)

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

**Main Activity** I'm naming my project "MyFirstApp"

```
    using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace MyFirstApp
{
    [Activity (Label = "MyFirstApp", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout** res/layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Strings**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```

**Please help me i'm beginner in android development**
if there is anything not clear i'll try to add more details
i'm using Xamarin for developing

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add the attribute:

```
android:id="@+id/myButton"
```

to your button in the layout xml file.

Then in your Activity you can find your button like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
```

Instead of:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
```

Update: Well, the findViewById I propsed was plain Android, not sure how it works in Xamarin, but for sure your button needs an id in the xml

Update 2: Actually you already had and Id for your button, but it is not myButton, it is `button_send` ==> so you may want to use that one instead `myButton`

Comment: which layout? activity_main.xml or content_main.xml?

Answer (score 2):

in your layout, the button id is - button_send:

```
android:id="@+id/button_send"
```

So in the activity code, when you "finding" this button, you should use that id, so instead

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
```

You should use

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button_send);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some internal scaffolding piece is generating bogus code assuming the identity of the button added to the layout. There is no context by which to determine which of the two buttons added for the walk through is supported by 'MyButton'. I just renamed it the "Translate Button" because I added that button first. Not sure what I'll do when I start with real apps.

Back in the old days, we would give this type of stuff to an in-house user to make sure it was suitable instructional material.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird issue, Resource by itself exists on a different namespace than the Resource where all your UI elements are defined.

Try using "MyFirstApp.Android.Resource.Id.button_send" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem.

You should do the following:

1) Cut or comment this code fragment:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
```

2) Build the project

3) Add the code in p. 1 again (Paste or uncomment)

Answer (score -2):

I can see only one Button in your Layout and the id of this Button is button_send.
Please try it with `(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);`